# Using an IF in SQL query

Tags: sql

I am very new to writing queries in SQL.

I have a query whose part below creates a value of 0.33 in the `REMU_Unclear` column if the case grade is Unclear. If the grade is not unclear then `NULL`.

I need to add a IF argument that states that if the Sale_Date is greater then or equal to 01.04.2017 and unclear then enter 0.25, else before 1st April and unclear 0.33 if not unclear NULL.

```
,CASE WHEN BusinessQuality.CaseGrade = 'Unclear' Then 0.33
      WHEN BusinessQuality.CaseGrade = 'Unclear (Grade Change)' Then 0.33 
      Else null
 END AS REMU_Unclear
```

I hope that this is everything required for some help.
Thanks
Ted

Comment: You've got all the syntax there that you need to achieve this. Why not give it a go?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this way:

```
,CASE WHEN BusinessQuality.CaseGrade = 'Unclear%' AND Sale_Date >= '2017-04-01' Then 0.25
      WHEN BusinessQuality.CaseGrade = 'Unclear%' AND Sale_Date < '2017-04-01' Then 0.33
      Else null
 END AS REMU_Unclear
```

I grouped 'Unclear (Grade Change)' and 'Unclear' using  'Unclear%' check if it is correct to your data or replace it back.

Comment: Thanks Matt that's worked a treat I also had to add another condition for another date range which also worked